How to test if element clicked on has id in an array?
As a learning experiment, I've created a page that includes elements with a certain set of ids. The objective is to perform an action if the element clicked on has an id in that set. The code is in a script collect.js. The problem is that the line let needToKnow = ids.incudes(whodat); throws the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'incudes')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (collect.js:7:30)

The goal is to render a modal if needToKnow is true. But how do I get past the line that fails?
window.onload = (function () {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    const ids = Array.from(images, (image) => image.id);

    document.addEventListener("click", (event, ids) => {
        let whodat = event.target.getAttribute('id');
        let needToKnow = ids.incudes(whodat); // fails here
        alert(needToKnow);
    });

});


Remove argument , ids and typo in includes.

Dopey me! & thanks for the good eye! Those permutations never occurred to me. Post as answer please.

You have included an extra argument ids in your function, which gets assigned undefined by default, causing this error. Also there's a typo in .includes:
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let whodat = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    let needToKnow = ids.includes(whodat);
    alert(needToKnow);
});


A little more streamlined as you can access most HTML attributes as properties of their DOM representations.


let ids = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    alert(ids.includes(event.target.id));
});
<p id="one">Click me!</p>   <!-- true -->
<p id="two">Click me!</p>   <!-- true -->
<p id="three">Click me!</p> <!-- true -->
<p id="four">Click me!</p>  <!-- true -->
<p id="five">Click me!</p>  <!-- true -->
<p id="six">Click me!</p>   <!-- false -->



